# Sticky website header working only partially on mobile

Tags: html, css

Currently, I have one of those partial sticky headers on the mobile version of my [site](https://templbodyco.com/) - it hides when you scroll down the page, and reappears as soon as you make the move to scroll up.

I don't know how it came to be this way in the first place, but it's there.

Anyways, what I want is for the header to stick permanently while scrolling.

I tried adding:

```css
#qodef-page-mobile-header {
position: sticky;
top: 0;
}
```

But there's no visible change. Maybe I have to change something in the current code somewhere but I have no clue where.

My coding knowledge is very limited so some simple instructions would be amazing. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```css
position: fixed;
top: 0;
```

Check this out [positition-fixed-vs-sticky](https://www.kevinpowell.co/article/positition-fixed-vs-sticky/)

Comment: Tried, still doesn't work, unfortunately.

Comment: @Varin That should to do it, hard to help you debug with only css, make sure you don't have any overriding css or javascript messing with you. Try using the `!important` rule.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).